# Insert static menu in backbone

Tags: html, backbone.js, menu

I have to insert a simple menu hard-coded in html, but I've no idea where should I insert it.
Should I add the html code directly in the router? and how?

Comment: Can you please explain briefly what you are trying to achieve? What's meant by static menu? why is it so special to make you be so confused where to insert it?

Answer (score 2):

No you should not use a router for that, you should do it in a Backbone.View object that's the kind of object that should be creating HTML and adding it.

***The Simpler Way without Templates***

```
 var view = Backbone.View.extend({
   .
   .   other backbone stuff
   .

   ,menu: '<div> menu </div>'

   ,render: function(){
      var compiledHTML= $(this.menu);
      $('selector').append(compiledHTML);
   }

 });
```

***The Simpler Way with Templates***

Use the HTML Menu inserted in your page HTML as using

.
     . your html code
     .

```
 .
 . end of your html code
 .

<script type="text/template" id="marker_small_info_template">
   <div> xxx </div>
</script>

</body>
```

and then in Backbone use Jquery to wrap it and add it to your page in the desired place.

```
 var view = Backbone.View.extend({

    ,render: function(){
      var compiledHTML= _.template( $("#marker_small_info_template").html());
      $('selector').append(compiledHTML);
      return this;
   }

 });
```

***The complex and fancy way of do it (require.js + templates)***

Is to have that HTML code as a template (Underscore.template for example) in a separate file and then "compile" it in a Backbone.View using Require.JS to fetch it for me, and use JQuery to wrap and add it.

```
define([  
  'text!templates/menuFrenteItem.html'
],
function (templateMenuItem) {

   return Backbone.View.extend({
  .
  .
  .
  ,smallInfo: function(variables){ return _.template(templateMenuItem, variables)}

  ,render: function(){
     var compiledHTML = $(this.smallInfo(dataToCompileTemplate));
     $('selector').append(compiledHTML);
     return this;
  }
```

}

I think this is a good opportunity to learn to use templates in Javascript and add this tool to your belt.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Backbone view, and have the router render it:

http://jsfiddle.net/rd13/g3U7j/11/

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.container',
    template: "<menu><li>Item</li></menu>",
    render: function() {
        this.el.innerHTML = this.template;
        return this;
    }
});

var r = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'default'
    },
    default: function() {
        new MyView().render();
    }                
});

var router = new r();
Backbone.history.start();​
```